# função que retorna o nome do campo chave de uma consulta (tfdquery), Delphi XE8

Tags: query, funções, crud, delphi-xe8

Estou preparando um CRUD em Delphi e preciso fazer uma função para encontrar o campo chave (*KeyField*) de um determinado registro localizado na consulta. 
A ideia é substituir o campo 'id' exigido pelo Locate por esta função e deixar o dataset configurado para assumir qualquer consulta nos formularios herdeiros(*inherited*). Vou demonstrar o código para ver se me entendem:

```
ds_Crud.DataSet.Locate('tpdoc_id',ds_Query.DataSet.FieldByName('tpdoc_id').Value,[loCaseInsensitive,loPartialKey]);
```

1. Meu ds_Crud é um TFDQUERY que executa as modificações no banco;
2. Meu ds_Query é um TFDQUERY que executa as consultas;

Minha tabsheet de dados deste form é acionada quando o registro é localizado pela ds_Query e é localizado pela chave primária na ds_Crud que entra em modo de edição para realizar EDIÇÃO ou EXCLUSÃO.

O problema é que não posso ficar digitando o código 'id' cada vez que realizo a consulta em forms herdados, preciso de uma função que retorne o nome do campo chave para filtrar o registro no DataSet CRUD, que seja virtual e abstrata do tipo (`function GetNomeKeyFiled: String;virtual;abstract;`) para assumir a posição do 'tpdoc_id' na linha de código acima do locate, ou algo que resolva este problema.